# show only year in query MS access Database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table i would only like to show the year in the query when i run it is this possible ?

[See the Table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXCtu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use use Access `DATEPART()` function :

```
SELECT t.*,DatePart("yyyy",t.DateColumn)
FROM YourTable t
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT Orders.OrderDate AS [Year],
       States.RegionName,
       States.DivisionName,
       Orders.OrderID AS [Number of Orders],
       DatePart("yyyy",Orders.OrderDate) as [Year_Col]
FROM Employees, Orders, States
GROUP BY Orders.OrderDate, States.RegionName, States.DivisionName, Orders.OrderID
ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate;
```

By the way, you are missing relations conditions, right now you are joining each record to each record on every one of the tables. Add a where clause

```
 WHERE Orders.Employee_id = employees.employee_id
   AND Orders.State_id = states.state_id
```

Of course I guessed the relations, adjust it to the actual ones.

Comment: how can i do this with the design view

Comment: at the moment my query looks like this
`SELECT Orders.OrderDate AS [Year], States.RegionName, States.DivisionName, Orders.OrderID AS [Number of Orders]
FROM Employees, Orders, States
GROUP BY Orders.OrderDate, States.RegionName, States.DivisionName, Orders.OrderID
ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate;
`